# Help with SQL query, how to add taxonomie terms with value stored in options?

Tags: categories, sql, options, pre-get-posts, posts-where

i need your help in making SQL

What i have:

1. custom post type ( company )
2. taxonomie ( category ) applyed to cpt ( and has ct section select field )
3. custom taxonomie ( section ) applyed to nothing

In taxonomie ( category ) i set value on custom field ( using acf plugin ) of custom taxonomie ( section ). and it stores in database like these:
in wp_options, key: `{taxonomie}_{term_id}_{field_key}`, value: `section_term_id`. For ex. i have category named "Wedding flowers" with id of 15 and tax. section term: "Weding" with id 14. So if i do: `get_option( 'category_15_section' )` i'll get `14` ( `_section` is field key, it could be `_aaa` or othere, but i for shore know that it will be `_section` )

So, what i need is when i'm on archive page of cpt and i have `$_GET['section']` variable ( wich is eaqual to `section term id == 14` ) I need to echo all posts in taxonomie ( category ), and that category must have value of custom fied wich has value in options table set up like `$_GET['section']`.

Hope u understand what i need, if not ask some clearifying moments in comments.

my code so far:

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', function( $query ) {
    if( ! is_main_query() || ! is_post_type_archive() || ! $query->get( 'section', false ) )
        return $query;

    $section = $query->get( 'section' );

    unset( $query->query['section'] );
    unset( $query->query_vars['section'] );
    $query->tax_query = false;
    $query->set( 'tax_query', false );

    add_filter( 'posts_where' , 'm7_24_section_posts_where' );

    //echo '<pre>'; var_dump( $query ); echo '</pre>';
    return $query;
} );
function m7_24_section_posts_where( $where ) {
    global $wpdb;
    remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );

    $section = (int) $_GET['section'];
    //echo '<pre>'; var_dump( $where ); echo '</pre>';

    // here i need to make sql to add categories wich have value in options table
    // set up like $section
    return $where;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ok folks, i did it anothere way.. here's how i did it:

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', function( $query ) {
    if( ! is_main_query() || ! is_post_type_archive() || ! $query->get( 'section', false ) )
        return $query;
    global $wpdb;

    $section = $query->get( 'section' );

    unset( $query->query['section'] );
    unset( $query->query_vars['section'] );
    $query->tax_query = false;
    $query->set( 'tax_query', false );

    $cateroties = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare(
        "
        SELECT option_name, option_value
        FROM $wpdb->options
        WHERE option_name LIKE '%s'
        ",
        'category_%_section'
    ) );

    $category__in = array();
    foreach( $cateroties as $category ) {
        $cat_id = $category->option_name;
        $values = unserialize( $category->option_value );
        if( in_array( $section, $values ) ) {
            $category__in[] = str_replace( 'category_', '', str_replace( '_section', '', $cat_id ) );
        }
        //
    }

    $query->set( 'category__in', $category__in );

    return $query;
} );
```